# using input from a text file for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have list of names of employees in a text file.

Instead of searching each name one by one, I want to search my database once for all the names of the text file. Some thing like:

```
select emplayeeID, Salary from employees where employee-name in "C:\myfile.txt"
```

Is it possible? If yes then what would be the SQL command for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, use [OPENROWSET with BULK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190312.aspx). You need a [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178129.aspx) file though.

```
select
    E.emplayeeID, E.Salary
from
    employees E
    JOIN
    OPENROWSET (
             BULK 'c:\myfile.txt',
             FORMATFILE = 'c:\myfileformat.txt'
    ) B ON E.name  = B.name
```

Comment: +1 sheeesh !! You always have those great ideas contradicting what I thought was the truth.... :-)

Comment: My friend, this is simply an awesome answer! +1 and if I could +10!

Comment: @marc_s, I guess we can all learn something new, even guys like you. I didn't figure you had anything left to learn my friend! :)

Comment: @gbn, if you have time, I opened a question that's a bit of a follow up to this one here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710332/openrowset-bulk-permissions-to-shared-folder, because I'm needing to pull the file from a shared drive.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>No, it's not possible - at least not in a single command.</strike>
*(see gbn's answer - if you want to, it **is** possible even in a single command....)*

What you could do is this:

- bulk load your employee names from the text file into a temporary table
- then do a JOIN between your `dbo.Employees` table and that temporary bulk-load table you've just filled

To bulk insert your names, use something like:

```
BULK INSERT EmployeeNames
FROM 'c:\myfile.txt'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

and then do your join:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.Salary 
FROM dbo.Employees e
INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeNames en ON e.Name = en.Name
```

Comment: Let me try this. Is it necessary to include "WITH..." statement if my text file has only one column with single/first name of the employees??

Comment: @kamari: you need to tell bulk insert how your fields are separated (`FIELDTERMINATOR=....`) and how your rows (lines) are separated, yes

Comment: Yeah got it....i just did as you suggested and it worked fine for me....Thanks an lot marc.....

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your text file into a comma separated string

```
select employeeID, Salary from employees where employee-name in ('Joe Blogs', 'Susan Smith', 'Jimi Hendrix')
```

A lot would depend on a) how big your text file is AND b) what platform you're using to construct your query.