# Getting the error-"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)". while importing data from Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, aceoledb

I  am getting the following error while importing data from Excel sheet to SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

I tried all the suggestions that are available but, still failing to resolve the error.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Can you put your code in here? The question is too broad.Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate. Good detailed answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987636/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked