# Export contents of SQL Server 2008 R2 table to CSV WITHOUT xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

I need to export the contents of a SQL SErver 2008 R2 Express table to a CSV or TXT file.

I cannot enable xp_cmdshell nor can I allow ad hoc distributed queries.

It needs to be executable from a trigger on one of the tables.

Comment: This sounds like a horrible hack to overcome an even more horrible design pattern. (Sorry, I don't mean to be rude.)  But if you really want to go down this path, you might look into a SQL Agent job with a job step containing a powershell script to export table data to a file. A trigger could invoke `msdb.dbo.sp_start_job`. But seriously, yuck!

Comment: Why does it need to be on a trigger? @DMason has it right IMO.

Comment: Yes, it is a horrible hack to try to get data out of an outdated system (circa 1999) where the source code would be extremely difficult to modify.  DB can be modified easily.  It's also running SQL Express, sorry I forgot to mention, so no SQL Agent. I only want the extract updated if there is new data, thus the trigger. My other solution is Task Scheduler with a PS script, but it seems stupid to keep running it when there may be no updates. The extract only needs to be created when there is new data. The extract is picked up and transferred to another system for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', '1';  
RECONFIGURE;  
EXEC sp_configure; 
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', '1';  
RECONFIGURE;  
EXEC sp_configure; 

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                       'Text;Database=C:\Temp\;HDR=Yes;',
                       'SELECT * FROM test.csv')
            (object_id, name)

SELECT 'object_id', 'name'

UNION ALL

SELECT object_id, name
FROM sys.tables

--This require csv file to be there at location
```

Follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987636/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked) , if you face any problem while insertion.

Once working you use same script in  trigger.

Comment: sorry, as stated in my post, I cannot enable 'ad hoc distributed queries'. I am assuming that this will not work otherwise. thanks though