# Export the content of a SQL Server table to a CSV without using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, stored-procedures, export-to-csv

I need to export the content of a Table into a file CSV.

I tried to use the execution of a `xp_cmdshell` from a stored procedure but it doesn't work because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server.

Do you know others way to write a file from a stored procedure?

Comment: Go through this link it may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028326/export-contents-of-sql-server-2008-r2-table-to-csv-without-xp-cmdshell

Comment: Can't use sql server's export utility ? Else : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/75329577-ea25-4898-b533-a6c311d051d9/export-data-from-stored-procedure-to-csv?forum=transactsql

Comment: @Srini131 I've tried the solution described in the link. But it use Ad Hoc Distributed Queries and I have this error:
SQL Server Database Error: SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server.

Comment: Thanks @PrabhatG, but I must export this table automatically during the execution of a Stored Procedure, not manually. And without use xp_cmdshell

Comment: You could do your own SP CLR in .Net to achieve this. Useful if you need custom stuff

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of methods you can try :

**1.** Using BCP

syntax :

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM Database.dbo.input" queryout C:\output.csv -c -t',' -T -S .\SQLEXPRESS
```

microsoft document : [BCP Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)

**2.** Second Method(for excel, but should work for csv too) :

```
Insert into OPENROWSET
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;',
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from SQLServerTable
```

For this, you need to enable adhoc distributed queries by following command :

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

you might encounter a link server error. So you should refer : [this stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987636/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked)