# How to import an Excel file into SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, excel

How can I import an Excel file into SQL Server database?

I am trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO temptable  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET( 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=\\team4\files\Update_66.xls','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I then run into this error:

> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
>   for linked server "(null)"

Is there a way to do this in powershell perhaps?

Please help me.

After reading Rigerta Demiri's code below, Here is my code:

```
 $dir = "\\server\files\"
    $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Where-Object {$_.name -like "xyzfile"}  | Select-Object -First 1
    $SQLServerConnection = "Data Source=rock;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=team;"
    $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $SQLServerConnection
    $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "temptable"
    $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($latest)
```

this code is giving me this error message:

```
Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "WriteToServer" and the argument count: "1".
```

Comment: Are You sure u can't use wizard of this? Import option?

Comment: Are you able to export the excel file as CSV? Bulk Insert can then be used.

Comment: Using the wizard can do but I would want to automate this process at some point. I am using powershell to write my scripts. @Kami, am trying to import the file into sql server database not exporting, do you guys have an idea of how I can accomplish this??

Comment: You could create an SSIS package and call it from a job that runs every 15 mins or so.  If a sheet exists in a specified location it will import it, if it doesn't it wont....type of idea.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987636/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked