# SQL Server maintenance plan archive to csv file and delete records

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I want to export the everyday data to a csv file and delete the records.

I have seen the standard maintenance plan has option to archive bak file only.

Is there any way **I write script and attach to maintenance plan** to do my tasks?
(**Per table**)

1. Export the records to CSV file (csv file name with current time)
2. Delete all the records from
       live DB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OPENROWSET` to export data through tsql and put this code inside your job :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @FileName AS VARCHAR(250)= 'Data-'+
       SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SYSDATETIME(), 121), ' ', ''), ':', '-'), '.', '-')+'.xls';

INSERT  INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database='+@FileName+';', 'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
SELECT  *
FROM    [YourTable];
WHERE < ... conditions ... >

DELETE  FROM [YourTable];
WHERE < ... conditions ... >

COMMIT;
```

I hope to be helpful :)

Comment: how to name the excel file as current time ?  like the bak named with timing.

Comment: use this `SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SYSDATETIME(), 121), ' ', ''), ':', '-'), '.', '-');`

Comment: where this select will go ? Database=D:\Data.xls;' here ?  Sorry.

Comment: Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)". Do you know any idea?

Comment: my db server is MS Sql server 2016 developer version.

Comment: There is no `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver` installed.
take a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987636/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked and here https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic564076-17-1.aspx and here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05258d18-d7e5-411d-b591-d98ba6674448/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-ibmdadb2-for-linked-server?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: Seems like new file wont't be created everytime ? I need to have file before insert ?                    Error Message "Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object,check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".

Comment: INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\DATA.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') SELECT * FROM Table1

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a windows service in a server side language like C# and have it run daily to retrieve the data, write it to a csv file and then delete the data?

Comment: Yes, Thats the final solution. Looking for anything can be attach inside SQL Serer Agent jobs.