# Oracle DB: query using file in where clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have just gone through the link [using input from a text file for WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562911/using-input-from-a-text-file-for-where-clause?answertab=active#tab-top) to query a table with input file.

But its not working with Oracle DB 11g. Is there any way to query the OIM tables with file inputs in Where Clause.

Comment: You know that question is for SQL Server, right? What is OIM? Is the file on a client machine or on the database server; and can it be moved to an Oracle-recognised directory on the server? If so, you could use an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm) for this maybe... struggling to find an exact duplicate question for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks External Table works. I was actually struggling for pointers. BULK Insert didn't work with Oracle DBs. Sorry OIM table is vague ..its set of Predefined tables in Oracle Identity Manager schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm) to refer to data in a flat file as part of a query.

In the example from the question you linked to, the equivalent would be something like:

```
create table employeenames (first_name varchar2(20))
organization external (
  type oracle_loader
  default directory my_dir
  location ('myfile.txt')
);
```

Then if the file contained first names you could find all employees with those names with:

```
select e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary 
from employeenames en
join employees e on e.first_name = en.first_name;
```

If the file just contained the single entry `David` that would give, with the `HR` schema I'm looking at:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                     SALARY
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ----------
        165 David                Lee                             6800 
        151 David                Bernstein                       9500 
        105 David                Austin                          4800
```

But the file has to be on the database server, and in a filesystem directory that Oracle has access to, and which is represented by an Oracle `DIRECTORY` object which points to that filesystem directory, and which the owner of the external table has permission to read from. So assuming this was run from the `SCOTT` account, you would have had to previously do this as a DBA:

```
create or replace directory my_dir as 'c:\';
grant read on directory my_dir to scott;
grant write on directory my_dir to scott;
```

Pointing to `c:\` probably isn't a good idea of course, you'd normally have a directory dedicated for this.